# mongTemplate aggregate match and projection one field without id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How do I run aggregate with match and projection. The projection includes one field and excludes id.

```
db.collection("Collection").aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "someCriteriaFlag" : false
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            "field1" : 1,
            "_id" : 0
        }
    }
]);
```

In Java

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("someCriteriaFlag").is(false)), 
        Aggregation.project("field1"));

List<String> fields= mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Collection", BasicDBObject.class)
        .getMappedResults();
```

Comment: Saw your edit. Use `andExcludes()` to exclude the `_id`.

Comment: @NeilLunn Answer please. I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NeilLunn.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("someCriteriaFlag").is(false)), 
    Aggregation.project("field1").andExclude("_id"));

List<String> fields= mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Collection", BasicDBObject.class)
    .getMappedResults();
```